# Given unsorted array, find i, j such that i < j and A[i] < A[j] in linear time and constant space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

**Example 1:**

Input: 5 4 3 2 1

Output: nil

**Example 2:**

Input: 5 4 3 2 6 1

Output: 0, 4 (indices)

Please suggest an algorithm to find such indices i, j that i < j and A[i] < A[j] in linear time and constant extra space. I have solved it in `O(n^2)` using 2 for loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um... I would immediately make an assumption that if such `i` and `j` exist at all, then there also must exist `i` and `j` such that `j == i + 1` and `A[i] < A[j]`. If so, the algorithm turns into a trivial single pass over the array.

In your second example that would be `i = 3` and `j = 4`.

Indeed, let's say we found `i` and `j` such that `A[i] < A[j]` and `i + 1 < j`. Let's take a look at `A[i + 1]`. If `A[i + 1]` is greater than `A[i]`, then just set `j = i + 1` and we are done. Otherwise, if `A[i + 1]` is smaller or equal to `A[i]`, then just set `i = i + 1` and repeat. This will always lead us to a `j == i + 1` pair that satisfies the `A[i] < A[j]` requirement.

In other words, just go over your array looking for `A[i] < A[i + 1]` situation. That's all there is to it.